# Lightbox inside Facebook?

Tags: facebook, popup, lightbox

Is it possible to place an picture in the FB timeline and when click on it, a popup window with an iframe or lighbox appears?

I want place an interactive video in the Timeline. Visitors must click on the picture without leaving the Facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't inject popups/Lightboxes into the Facebook Newsfeed.

You can try use swf, and their character of custom video players, to get some interactivity. But in general, people don't really enjoy that experience.